# In NSMutableArray methods, removeObject: vs removeObjectIdenticalTo:

Tags: objective-c

With regards to a NSMutableArray, what is the difference between **removeObject:** and **removeObjectIdenticalTo:**

The wording in the API Reference seems very similar:

> rO: Removes all occurrences in the
>   receiver of a given object
>
> rOIT: Removes all occurrences of a
>   given object in the receiver

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** I mean, how would I choose between them.

Comment: Just to note that, since this question was asked, the documentation for both methods has been updated to explicitly say how the objects are selected for removal.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`removeObjectIdenticalTo:` will remove the object that is being pointed to, `removeObject:` will run a `isEqual:` on all items in the array and remove it if it returns true.

Edit:

You should use `removeObjectIdenticalTo:` if you know you have the same object (like for NSViews or similar), and `removeObject:` for strings and objects where it may not be the same object, but should be considered equal for practical purposes.

Comment: Just to piggyback on @cobbal's answer. Consider the difference; **removeObject** goes to each object in the array and sends it the message **isEqual**. A class can implement this method to return **YES** or **NO** based on its own determination. For example, two objects could be considered equal if they had an identical property. The method **removeObjectIdenticalTo** removes an object if and only if it is the exact same object as the one passed in this message.

Answer (score 3):

@cobbal Really great answer :) After seeing your answer I really understood the difference. But at first it seemed little confusing for me since I'm a newbie to Objective-C programming so I just want to enhance your answer by providing an example. Hope it helps other newbies when they look at the example :)

```
#import<Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main()
{   int i;
    printf("Enter 1 to perform removeObject function.\n Enter 2 to perform removeObjectIdenticalTo functionality.\n ");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    @autoreleasepool{
    NSString* color;// int count;
    NSString * s1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Red"];
    NSString * s2 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Yellow"];
    NSString * s3 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Red"];
    NSString * s4 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Cyan"];
    NSMutableArray * myColors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: s1,s2,s3,s4,nil];

    if(i == 1)
    {
        [myColors removeObject: s1];    //will remove both s1 and s3 object because their contents are same
//we can also use [myColors removeObject: @"Red"]; instead of above statement. However the functionality remains same . 
        for(color in myColors)NSLog(@"%@",color); 
    }

    else if (i == 2){
        [myColors removeObjectIdenticalTo: s1];  //deletes only s1 object in the array myColor  
        for(color in myColors)NSLog(@"%@",color);
    }

    }
    return 0;
    }
```

PS : This is just a example. U can find the answer in @cobbal 's answer.